Time and Attendance query, First transaction of the day per person
I want to get the record to show who has been in on each day.
Its for a time and attendance where i need to see any record for a user per day.
Original Table



USERID
Time




2
2024-05-01 07:35:44.560


3
2024-05-01 07:44:21:221


1
2024-05-01 09:25:41.434


3
2024-05-01 10:05:27.310


1
2024-05-01 12:30:24.523


2
2024-05-01 15:55:11.230


2
2024-05-02 07:23:31.213


1
2024-05-02 09:20:35.710


3
2024-05-02 13:35:41.710


2
2024-05-02 16:05:23.534


1
2024-05-02 19:01:49.140


3
2024-05-02 19:18:35.113


1
2024-05-03 09:22:45.722



Wanted Table



USERID
Time




2
2024-05-01


3
2024-05-01


1
2024-05-01


2
2024-05-02


1
2024-05-02


3
2024-05-02


1
2024-05-03



Thanks
SQL2016
I have tried using MIN(Time) and group by Userid but this just shows the first record for each user in total and not by each day.
I would like to convert datetime to just date but mainly i need to display the records that show the userid and date but only once per day
This is what i have tried
SELECT  Top USERID, MIN(cast(ServerUTC AS DATE)) AS MinDate FROM   JournalLogView GROUP BY USERID ORDER BY MinDate Desc
EDIT
Thanks, i have managed to get what i needed above.
Next question is how can i add another field without grouping? i need to display the door name (can be any door used that day).
Original Table



USER
Time
Door




Paul
2024-05-01
Main


Dave
2024-05-01
Main


Paul
2024-05-01
Main


Paul
2024-05-01
Side


Paul
2024-05-02
Main


Paul
2024-05-02
Main


Paul
2024-05-02
Back


Dave
2024-05-02
Back


Dave
2024-05-02
Main



Need



USER
Time
Door




Paul
2024-05-01
Main


Dave
2024-05-01
Main


Paul
2024-05-02
Main


Dave
2024-05-02
Back



SELECT USER, CAST(Time AS DATE) AS Date, Door
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY USER, CAST(Time AS DATE)
ORDER BY Date, USER, Door;


So you don't want the time but rather just the date? Then simply convert your datetime into date. select distinct userid, convert(date, time) from table1.

may be SELECT USERID,CAST(Time AS DATE)AS DATE_D,COUNT(*)AS CNTT FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY USERID,CAST(Time AS DATE)

"I have tried using MIN(Time) and group by Userid ..."  So where's this try???  We don't see it.

Please update your question with the actual code you tried so we may assist you in fixing it (debugging details) ; this site is not a coding service but we are totally available to help you with what you tried.

I would like to convert datetime to just date but mainly i need to display the records that show the userid and date but only once per day.

Please edit your question to add clarity not add comments which many may not see.

Your group by must select the date cast as a "date" (no time) and your GROUP by must contain your userId and your timestamp cast as a date as well. or it will not "GROUP" by both the user ID and date.  Note you're assuming in your time in attendance that the occurance of a "day" is enough; you're not traking minutes/hours per day or anything like that right? (If I show up at 8:00 time in and then time out at 8:15 I get credit for the whole day?)

To get what you are looking for in SQL Server, This can be done by converting the Time column to a date (which will strip off the time part) and then using GROUP BY on both USERID and the date. You don't need to use MIN(Time) since you are just interested in seeing if a record exists for a user on each day.
Here is the SQL query that will generate the result you are looking for:
SELECT USERID, CAST(Time AS DATE) AS Date
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY USERID, CAST(Time AS DATE)
ORDER BY Date, USERID;

CAST(Time as DATE): This converts the Time column to just the date part, ignoring the time.
GROUP BY USERID, CAST(Time AS DATE): This will group the records by both USERID and the date, ensuring that you get one record per user per day.
ORDER By Date, USERID will ensure the order by date and user.
Here is the output:



USERID
Date




1
2024-05-01


2
2024-05-01


3
2024-05-01


1
2024-05-02


2
2024-05-02


3
2024-05-02


1
2024-05-03



